# Split table data in SQL and replace with results

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, split, substring

I need to remove a bunch of unneeded data from each table based on split parameters.

My SQL table is storing a bunch of HTML for caching, The data is already in SQL and it's growing to be quite large so now I want to split some of the data I don't use from each table based on a string and update the table with the new results.

cacheHTML table is holding data like this

```
<html>
... (a bunch of data I don't need)
<first div>
... (the data I do want to save)
</div>
... (data I don't care about also)
</html>
```

I only want whats inside the first div and to remove all the html up to that point.

Is there any easy method for this? I need to do this to 5k rows of cached data...

I need a function or method to say give me everything between string1 till string2 then replace the table with the results. Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide an example schema, and sample data?

Comment: You don't want to do this in pure SQL. Get a language you know a lot about that can connect to your database (Perl, Python, Ruby, Java, C#, hell even C++, whatever you're best at). This is quite easy with a regular expression.

Comment: **What** database and version are you using? String and XML support is very different from vendor to vendor..... also: can you guarantee that your HTHL is really XHTML compliant (true-blue XML)?? That would make things **a lot** easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. Will only work if you always need the text inside the first div in the html string. Im assuming SQL Server as database system but it could probably be translated to others pretty easily.

Sample html string:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stuff i dont need</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Stuff i dont need</title>
    <p>I dont need any of this data</title>
    <div>This is the data i need to save!</div>
    <h3>Dont need this</h3>
    <div>Wont need this either!<div>
    <h3>Bye</h3>
</body>
```

SQL to do the update:

```
UPDATE cacheHTML
SET htmlText = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(htmlText, CHARINDEX('<div>', htmlText, 0), CHARINDEX('</div>', htmlText, 0) - CHARINDEX('<div>', htmlText, 0)), '<div>', '')
```

Comment: The 3rd value of the substring seems to be giving an error:

"Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

The first CHARINDEX is working but the 2nd for the END is not.

Comment: Found out whats happening my HTML data is about 10k per table, and it seems CHARINDEX has a data size limitation for anything above 8k

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/966-SQL-CHARINDEX-Has-Data-Size-Limitations.htm

Comment: What is the datatype of the column holding your HTML string? It should work if you use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).

Comment: nText due to such large length and also needed to hold UTF-8 results.

Comment: You should really use nvarchar(max) instead. nText and Text is deprecated and will be removed in a future realease of SQL Server. Also, nvarchar(max) and varchar(max) can hold up to 2gb of data, so you should be covered + they work with string functions like SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx